# React Native - Short text inside flex: 1 view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a text inside a row which has 2 views with flex: 1

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 5 }}>
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <Text>Just a reallyyyyyyyy longgggg text</Text>
   </View>

   <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
      <Button style={{width: 130, height: 30}} ... />
   </View>
</View>
```

With this implementation, the second view overlaps the text of the first one **if it is too long**.

How can I make the long texts of the component seems like: "Hello w..." if they are overlaped by the second view?

Comment: <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">..</Text>

Comment: @UğurEren thanks man you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Just read the description and I could find the by using CSS.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap", padding: 5 }}>
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <Text>Just a reallyyyyyyyy longgggg text</Text>
   </View>

   <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
      <Button style={{width: 130, height: 30}} ... />
   </View>
</View>
```

You should add `flexWrap: wrap` to the View tag.